# I have not found a way to line break after completing 100 units in Angular flex layout

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

How to give a line break after completion of 100 units in Angular flex layout

My code is

```
 <div class="content" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlexFill>
    <div fxFlex="50" fxFlex.xs="50" fxFlex.gt-md="50">
          Col 1
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="50" fxFlex.xs="50" fxFlex.gt-md="50">
          Col 2
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="50" fxFlex.xs="50" fxFlex.gt-md="50">
          Col 3
    </div>
</div>`
```

It is supposed to take a line break after col2, i.e Col 1 & Col 2 in first line containing width 50%, 50% respectively and in third line Col 3 with 50%.

But it is not working like that, executing all cols in first line. for a work around I am making two rows for now, absolutely that's not the recommended way.

Comment: You want to allow your flex container to `wrap` its items …

Comment: `fxLayout="row wrap"`. Read [the documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Declarative-API-Overview) next time, please.